# "This site can’t be reached" error after installing Varnish on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, configuration-files, varnish

/etc/varnish/default.vcl :

```
backend default {
    .host = "static ip here";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

I am hosting my site on a AWS EC2 instance. The site was working fine until I installed Varnish.
I restarted both apache and varnish after making the above changes.

Please help.

Comment: Are the ports on your security groups allowing traffic from port 8080 in?

Comment: Yes, here is a picture - http://i.imgur.com/Fc3vvuJ.png

Comment: Can you SSH to the instance?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh into it and do `apt-get update` and stuff.

Comment: Have you followed steps 2 and 3 of this tutorial?  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3